# Write to textbox during animation

Tags: powerpoint

I have 4 pictures that are faded in (when I click space or mouse). But I want to add a text field to every picture and ask my students what is it that is faded in next? The first picture fades in, the studens say "Oh it is a TV" and now I want to write TV into the textbox and continue with the next picture.

Problem is, that I cannot click into the textfield I added, since as soon as I click my mouse the next picutre fades out. I already check a lot of forums but coult not find anything. Anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set that text box (pre-written) as an object, setting it to fade-in like you're fading in your photos. You can't type text when the PPT is in presentation mode.